# Rails/MySQL ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have this confusing error message `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique`

This is my model: `artisan.rb` :

```
class Artisan < ActiveRecord::Base
  require 'csv'

  validates :nom_entreprise, presence: true
  validates :nom_entreprise_format_url, presence: true
  validates :adresse_1, presence: true
  validates :code_postal, presence: true
  validates :ville, presence: true
  validates :gps_latitude, presence: true
  validates :gps_longitude, presence: true
  validates :url_site_artisan, presence: true
  validates :telephone, presence: true

  csv_text = File.read('artisans.csv')
  csv = CSV.parse(csv_text, :headers => true)
  csv.each do |row|
    Artisan.create!(row.to_hash)
  end
end
```

the controller:

```
class ArtisansController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @artisans = Artisan.all 
  end
end
```

I also give you `schema.rb`:

```
  create_table "artisans", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "nom_entreprise",            limit: 255
    t.string   "nom",                       limit: 255
    t.string   "prenom",                    limit: 255
    t.string   "adresse_1",                 limit: 255
    t.string   "adresse_2",                 limit: 255
    t.integer  "code_postal",               limit: 4
    t.string   "ville",                     limit: 255
    t.float    "gps_latitude",              limit: 24
    t.float    "gps_longitude",             limit: 24
    t.string   "description",               limit: 255
    t.string   "url_site_artisan",          limit: 255
    t.string   "url_voir_plus",             limit: 255
    t.float    "telephone",                 limit: 24
    t.string   "nom_entreprise_format_url", limit: 255
    t.boolean  "visible_site_web"
    t.datetime "created_at",                            null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                            null: false
  end
```

At last but not least, the error message :

```
Started GET "/admin/artisans" for ::1 at 2017-07-12 11:40:37 +0200
Processing by RailsAdmin::MainController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"model_name"=>"artisans"}
[RailsAdmin] Could not load model Artisans, assuming model is non existing. (uninitialized constant Artisans)
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO `artisans` (`id`, `nom_entreprise`, `nom`, `prenom`, `adresse_1`, `adresse_2`, `code_postal`, `ville`, `gps_latitude`, `gps_longitude`, `description`, `url_site_artisan`, `url_voir_plus`, `telephone`, `nom_entreprise_format_url`, `visible_site_web`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (10, 'La Brasserie du Baril', 'NULL', 'NULL', '4, Rue Champlain', 'NULL', 29200, 'Brest', 48.3818645, -4.529462500000022, 'NULL', 'http://www.brasseriedubaril.com', 'NULL', 9.0, 'la-brasserie-du-baril', 1, '2017-07-12 09:40:37', '2017-07-12 09:40:37')
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 24ms (ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique (Mysql2::Error: Duplicate entry '10' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO `artisans` (`id`, `nom_entreprise`, `nom`, `prenom`, `adresse_1`, `adresse_2`, `code_postal`, `ville`, `gps_latitude`, `gps_longitude`, `description`, `url_site_artisan`, `url_voir_plus`, `telephone`, `nom_entreprise_format_url`, `visible_site_web`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (10, 'La Brasserie du Baril', 'NULL', 'NULL', '4, Rue Champlain', 'NULL', 29200, 'Brest', 48.3818645, -4.529462500000022, 'NULL', 'http://www.brasseriedubaril.com', 'NULL', 9.0, 'la-brasserie-du-baril', 1, '2017-07-12 09:40:37', '2017-07-12 09:40:37')):
  app/models/artisan.rb:17:in `block in <class:Artisan>'
  app/models/artisan.rb:16:in `<class:Artisan>'
  app/models/artisan.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

The error messages at the beginning says that the model "artisans" couldn't be loaded cause it doesn't exists. It's true!To create this model i ran `rails g model Artisan` and **not** `rails g model Artisans`

One last thing: the error occurred in the admin interface but also in the view (there's nothing in the view yet).
I was able to see the content of Artisan in the admin and then went away and the error message was displayed.

Any help of any kind would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: I guess your csv has value for `ID` as well, which you should not be manually inserting to DB. i.e. `row.to_hash` will have a key `ID`, skip it. Rails should take care of that column

Comment: to skip it use `row.to_hash.except(:id_column_name)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL, PRIMARY KEY constraint uniquely identifies each record in a database table. Primary keys must contain UNIQUE values, and cannot contain NULL values. And, a table can have only one primary key. 
Rails by default take care of maintaining a unique primary key(ie id) in the database. It also validates the uniqueness of the primary key. But, the above code is trying to save a duplicate 'id' using the code `Artisan.create!(row.to_hash)`

You can fix this issue by omitting "id" attribute during creating.

```
 csv.each do |row|
   Artisan.create!(row.to_hash.except("id"))
 end
```

Comment: It works! Thank you. This piece of code won't have any other effect in the future? Like when i'll have to manipulate the ids?

Comment: It's better not to use "id" column to store any user defined values in rails. Replace "id" column in your CSV file to something else. Then the above code will work perfectly.

Comment: i think the each statement is causing an issue in my back office. Artisans are duplicated every time i reload the page

Comment: You need to put your code inside a method and call only when it is needed. In this case, each time you call the Artisan model records are getting extracted from the CSV file.

Comment: Okay i'll try to do that